# Finding the original file of a symbolic link

Tags: symlink

So let's say I have a symbolic link of a file in my home directory to another file on a different partition. How would I find the target location of the linked file? By this, I mean, let's say I have `file2` in `/home/user/`; but it's a symbolic link to another `file1`. How would I find `file1` without manually having to go through each partition/directory to find the file?

Comment: Please expand on "original file". What if `file1` is a symlink to `file0` ? Do you want to find the last target of your symlink (`file0`) or just the next one (`file1`) ?

Comment: Drag and drop the link to firefox.
Firefox will show the original file address as URL.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use **readlink**:

```
readlink -f /path/file
```

( last target of your symlink if there's more than one level )

If you just want the next level of symbolic link, use:

```
readlink /path/file
```

You can also use **realpath** on modern systems with [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html) (e.g. [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html)),  [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=realpath&sektion=1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/realpath.1), [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/realpath.1) or [DragonFly](https://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=realpath&section=1):

```
realpath /path/file
```

which is similar to `readlink -f`.

Comment: im getting no output

Comment: You should have one ! Error or a path

Comment: no nothing: `user@shell a5$ readlink -f ./student1.java`
and i get `user@shell a5$`

Comment: nvm, my symbolic link wasnt setup right, not sure why. but i made a new one and it works, thanks.

Comment: FWIW `readlink /path/file` will return the next target.

Comment: I think nowadays realpath(1) is considered the right way; usage is v similar to readlink..

Answer (score 8):

1.

```
ls -l bin
```

produce

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 az az 14 Ноя 12 22:13 bin -> ../Gdrive/bin/
```

2.

```
file bin
```

produce

```
bin: symbolic link to `../Gdrive/bin/'
```

3.

```
stat bin
```

produce

```
File: «bin» -> «../Gdrive/bin/»
```

Comment: ok well im trying to make a script, so how would i use these? im new to linux.

Comment: @k-Rocker If you explain what you intend to do it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way: `cd` to where the symbolic link is located and do `ls -l` to list the details of the files.

The part to the right of `->` after the symbolic link is the destination to which it is pointing.

Ex:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 userName groupName 22 Jan 17 13:29 Link to temp.txt -> /home/user/temp.txt

Here we have "Link to temp.txt" that points to (`->`) "/home/user/temp.txt".

But, like [@Gilles Quenot points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167632/114401), you can also just do `readlink -f /path/to/symbolic_link`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Costas

Suppose you have

```
ln -s test.txt sym_link_1.txt
ls -l sym_link_1.txt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 a1 g1 8 Jan  7 16:59 sym_link_1.txt -> test.txt
```

In a script you can do (use backticks)

```
ln -s `readlink sym_link_1.txt` sym_link_2.txt
```

Then you have

```
ls -l sym_link_*.txt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 a1 g1 8 Jan  7 16:59 sym_link_1.txt -> test.txt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 a1 g1 8 Jan  7 17:01 sym_link_2.txt -> test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method (which are not answered previously) to find link files is to use the below command,

```
file -h <path_to_dir>/* | grep link
```

**Command**:

```
file -h /home/prateek/* | grep link
```

**Output**:

/home/prateek/Music:                      symbolic link to /media/prateek/HD-E1/Music